# UE4 Increasing NAME_SIZE limit

Tags: unreal-engine4, cesiumjs

I am using Cesium plugin with Unreal Engine 4. I have to load the tileset into Cesium3DTileset and the tileset is in the private bucket. To access the objects in the private bucket, I am using CloudFront Signed Cookie (Since Cesium3DTileset needs to access other helper files). However, since there is no way to send Cookie, I am sending it as a query parameter attached to the URL. But this makes the URL very long hence causing `FName's 1023 max length exceeded. Got 1405 characters excluding null-terminator`.

So, I wonder if there is a better/alternative way to achieve my goal. One way I can think of is increasing the **NAME_SIZE from 1024 to some higher value**. But I am not sure how to do that or if that is even possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API you're using but I don't understand why a URL would be represented by an `FName` rather than an `FString`. This is far from the intended usage of `FName`s.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider this a bug in Cesium for Unreal, and I wrote an issue for it here:
https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium-unreal/issues/617